# How to capture all commands triggering cmd.exe to open on windows10?

Tags: windows, cmd, scheduler, trace

i have scheduler commands running on local PC. scheduler commands come from another server.
command is causing cmd.exe to open and do processing and close.

i have done a lot of debug to find out what is the command received by PC, 
which is causing cmd.exe to pop up. i want to find out whether its `cmd.exe /c command` ? or a `cmd.exe command`.
i couldn't find, as it is handled by application.

i would be very appreciating your help, if any one has solution.

Comment: Are you looking for `echo %cmdcmdline%`?

Comment: Read it in Task Manager's Detail tab. Add the commandline column.

Comment: @Stephan thanks for the fast response. it helped me to find which shell been used.

Comment: i'm looking for something like, open another command prompt shell, run any command which can show all the history of executions especially on cmd.exe pop ups which have opened and closed with full paths. my interest is on full path including cmd.exe and arguments passed to it.